# How to change background and text colors in Yakuake?

Tags: terminal, kde, colors

I like Yakuake, but I don't like the grey background color. I want to change the background and text colors of the Yakuake terminal.

I checked the options, but the background color option is only changing the bottom tab bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the menu of Yakuake. As far as I understood correctly you only tried changing color in:

```
Menu -> Config Yakuake
```

But there should be also

```
Menu -> Manage Profiles -> Appearance
```

There you can choose a profile for the shell in Yakuake and you can set several colors in the same way like you can do in Konsole.

Answer (score -3):

A quick google search will give you may be an answear : http://williamarchibaldspooner.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/install-yakuake-ubuntu-installation-and-set-up-guide/

Comment: Actually I already visited the page. It doesn't have any details on how to do it. It shows a background option but that doesn't change the terminal color. It changes the bottom tab bar.

Comment: And for that you need to give a -1 on the answer ? PS: You have in the menu an appearance option. You can change values in there and apply them by default. And juste another thing, your probably not so good at searching. You have also this option here to tune up yakuake : http://kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=87

Comment: It is not working. It is not changing the background color. As I said it only changes the color of the tabs below. The above answer is working. Profiles have to be changed.

Comment: See above answer!

Comment: In the link I provided you, they also mention that you need to change the profiles. But I think that you didn't did the effort to really read the article to the end. So your -1 should be a +1.

Comment: I really didn't know what profiles are, so I was confused. I thought I could upvote once you gave a clear answer. But it figures you can't change your vote after 1 hour. But you have to remember many people in the future are gonna search the answers and the link may have expired then and your answer is gonna be useless.

Comment: In the case you are confused you ask, and you don't do stuff based on something you don't understand or don't know. And the link as you can see is still there even if it was posted in 2011. So let others judge if the link is useless when it will be and not before. With that said I'm done.